# unable to delete __ci_last_regenerate from session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This `__ci_last_regenerate` is screwing my session. Is there a way of removing this from session array ?

When i set session for user and i print session, the session array is created correctly but its is proceeded by `__ci_last_regenerate`. Also when i destroy session the session array has only one element and its that bloody `__ci_last_regenerate`.

Session after login :

```
array(2) { 
      ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1475532963) 
      ["cb7a1d775e800fd1ee4049f7dca9e041eb9ba083"]=> array(2) { 
              ["id"]=> string(2) "37" 
              ["email"]=> string(19) "admin@admin.com" 
      } 
}
```

Session after logout (when calling session destroy)

```
array(1) { 
       ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1475533350) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to delete that. The library uses it internally - that's why it is re-created every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('__ci_last_regenerate');
```

Did you try this ?

Comment: This is not going to work as the value is regenerated on refresh. Already tried btw :)